# How to use ng-class on a top level container when using nested views

Tags: angularjs, view

I am trying to import a [toggleable sidebar](http://rdash.github.io) and trying to use nested views so that I can dynamically change content of each section individually. 
My app has 3 main components

1) a sidebar 
2) a header 
3) a content area

The problem I have is that in the original project everything is inside a single controller and there is an ng-class that toggles the sidebar which is can be toggled on clicking, but I am unable to reproduce it in the my application.

Here is what my index.html code looks like at the moment

```
<div id="page-wrapper" ng-class="{'open': toggle}" ng-cloak>
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" ui-view="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
                <!-- Header Bar -->
                <div class="row header" ui-view="header">
                </div>
                <!-- Header Bar -->
                <div ui-view="content" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my route config.

```
.state('home', {
              url: '/',
            views: {
                'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeCtrl as home'
                      },
                'sidebar': {
                        controller: 'SidebarCtrl as sidebar',
                          templateUrl: 'sidebar.html'
                      },
                'header': {
                            controller: 'HeaderCtrl as header',
                            templateUrl: 'header.html'
                    }
            }

          });
```

I am confused on how I can toggle the sidebar using ng-class as I cannot place it inside any other template for it to work.

Comment: you can create another controller on the outer div that keeps the state of the toggle: <div id="page-wrapper" ng-controller="myctrl" ng-class="{'open': toggle}" ng-cloak>

Comment: Do i need to add it to the states ?

Comment: No, you can add controllers to any element using the ng-controller directive, see the html fragment in my previous comment. You have to declare the controller in one of the script files, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous comments as an answer:

in your html:

```
<div id="page-wrapper" ng-controller="myctrl" ng-class="{'open': toggle}" ng-cloak>
  ...
</div>
```

in your script file:

```
.controller('myctrl',[ '$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.toggle = true;  // open initially
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I was confused on whether i could add a controller without adding it to the states. Thanks